# Getting all children of collection with has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

If I have a collection of `Post`s, is there anyway to get all `Comment`s for all of those posts using method chaining or scopes?

For example:

```
posts = Post.where(published: true)
comments = posts.comments

# vs 
comments = []
posts.each do |post|
  comments.push(post.comments)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way:

```
Comment.joins(:post).where(post: {published: true})
```

or if you have a `posts` variable that is a ActiveRecord Relation:

```
Comment.joins(:post).where(post: posts)
```

Answer (score 10):

Sure, there are a few ways. You can can use `map` and `flatten`, which is fine for a small number of records. Make sure you load the comments in bulk by using `includes`.

```
Post.where(published: true).includes(:comments).map(&:comments).flatten
```

Or you can use a join. This puts more work on the database, which is likely faster, but depends on your schema and dataset. You will typically want to use `uniq` to prevent duplicates.

```
posts = Post.where(published: true)
Comment.joins(:post).merge(posts).uniq
```

Also, make sure that you fully qualify any explicit fragments in any clauses on joined tables, e.g. use `where('posts.created_at < ?', ...)` instead of `where('created_at < ?', ...)`.

**Edit:**

Another variant on the first, in case you want to return a relation (which can be further scoped down the line):

```
Comment.where(id: Post.where(published: true).pluck(:id))
```

Comment: Maybe `Comment.where(post_id:`?